# Get names of all files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

On an ASP.NET MVC project I need to load the names of all files in the porject so I tried:

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles("~", @"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

But I get the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\~'.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

the `~` symbol of ASP.net describes the path of the application root directory. What you have to to is to use `Server.MapPath("~")` in order to get the physical path to your app root.

```
String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~"), @"*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```